# wpf RadioButton Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using one boolean property to set two Radio Buttons IsChecked Property
Here is my xaml code

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Group1" Content="Radio1" IsChecked="{Binding BooleanProperty}"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="Group1" Content="Radio2" IsChecked="{Binding BooleanProperty,Converter={StaticResource BooleanNotConverter}}"/>
```

The above piece of code is inside the child view of my main window. First time when i load the child view the radio button works fine. 
Second time when i load the child view the viewmodel's BooleanProperty setter called unexpectedly.i am not setting the property value from any where.

Here is my view model property

```
public bool BooleanProperty
{
        get;
        set;
}
```

please help me to find if i am doing something wrong..

Comment: You are talking about two different properties, but there is only one in example...

Comment: Sorry .. Using only one property. Question is modified.. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure, that you closed child view after first call? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Try to set default value for this property in constructor, and then it should works fine, imho.

Comment: yes i am using Prism framework to dispose the viewmodel. Setting the KeepAlive = false

Comment: I have limitation to set the property in constructor because on set there are lot of functionality that is supposed to happen. And it is expected to happen only when user really set/unset the radio button

Comment: So, your problem is: on the first view load BooleanProperty is true and on the second - false (or vise versa). Am I correct?

Comment: yes .Exactly.. first it is false and second time its true

Comment: In my opinion, you have to do refactoring and separate your logic and setting of default values of properties. I have no ideas what reason of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be resolved by avoid using groupName . if we use the groupName on dispose of the view the bounded property of radio button property will be set automatically

```
<RadioButton Name="radio1" Content="Radio1" IsChecked="{Binding BooleanProperty}"/>


<RadioButton  Content="Radio2" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName= radio1,Converter={StaticResource BooleanNotConverter}}"/>
```