# WPF RadioButton Binding issue when linked with the SelectedItem of a Datagrid

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, radio-button

First, sorry for my english.
I have a problem in a project I'm working on and I can't put the finger on what is wrong.
I would really appreciate if someone can help me or give me an advice to solve this issue.
I could create a minimal reproduction case to better explain my issue:

Let's create a class called Foo:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo(byte _id, string _name)
        { 
            ID = _id;
            Name = _name;
        }
        public byte ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Option1 { get; set; }
        public bool Option2 { get; set; }
        public bool Option3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in the MainWindow, let's create an 'ObservableCollection' called 'Foos' and populate it with some values:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;

            Foos.Add(new Foo(1, "foo 1") { Option1 = true });
            Foos.Add(new Foo(2, "foo 2") { Option2 = true });
            Foos.Add(new Foo(3, "foo 3") { Option3 = true });

        }
    }
```

In the UI, I have now a datagrid binded to Foos displaying some elements (Name & ID).
On the right side I have some RadioButton linked to the 'SelectedItem' of the datagrid displaying the Option 1,2&3:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <DataGrid x:Name="DtgSource" ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              Width="100"
              SelectionChanged="DtgSource_SelectionChanged"
              SelectedValuePath="Name">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <RadioButton GroupName="Options" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=DtgSource,
            Path=SelectedItem.Option1}" Content="Option 1"/>
        <RadioButton GroupName="Options" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=DtgSource,
            Path=SelectedItem.Option2}" Content="Option 2"/>
        <RadioButton GroupName="Options" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=DtgSource,
            Path=SelectedItem.Option3}" Content="Option 3"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

**The Problem** is that sometimes, when I select an object in the datagrid, the options change even if I never clicked on any radiobutton:
I have this behaviour:

- Select Foo 1: radiobutton state: Op1:True | Op2:False | Op3:False
- Select Foo 2: radiobutton state: Op1:False | Op2:True | Op3:False
- Select Foo 3: radiobutton state: Op1:False | Op2:False | Op3:True
- Select Foo 1: radiobutton state: Op1:True | Op2:False | Op3:False
- Select Foo 3: radiobutton state: Op1:False | Op2:False |**Op3:False**

[image: ui]

Did I missed something or is there a better implementation to avoid this behaviour?
On the project I'm working on, I have other controls than radiobutton and I  face this issue only with the RadioButton.

I tried with other Control for the selection panel such as ListView and ListBox. -> same behaviour

I tried also to implement Foo differently to have more information to debug and to catch the moment the options are modified:
SelectionChanged method:

```
    private void DtgSource_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var d = sender as DataGrid;
        Foo selitem = d.SelectedItem as Foo;
        Console.WriteLine($"SelectionChanged to {d.SelectedValue}| options -> {selitem.Option1}|{selitem.Option2}|{selitem.Option3}");
    }
```

Option implementation for debugging:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        private bool option1;
        public bool Option1 { get => option1; set { if (option1 != value) { option1 = value; Console.WriteLine($"{Name}|Option1 set to {value}"); } } }
    //...
```

And as described, The output in the console is as follow:

```
SelectionChanged to foo 1| options -> True|False|False 
SelectionChanged to foo 2| options -> False|True|False  
SelectionChanged to foo 3| options -> False|False|True 
foo 3|Option3 set to False
SelectionChanged to foo 1| options -> True|False|False
SelectionChanged to foo 3| options -> False|False|False
```

By inserting a breakpoint on the 'set' of any options and looking at the call stack, I see that the call has been done by 'external code' -> the UI

/!\ Before asking this question I could find this : [wpf RadioButton Binding Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770987/wpf-radiobutton-binding-issue)
That seems related. But the accepted answer is saying to avoid using the 'GroupName' property. It's something that I tried and sadly, the behaviour is exactly the same.

As I said, any help would be really appreciated to understand what is happening here :)

Comment: Set the  binding mode on the IsChecked property Binding to OneWay. It's TwoWay by default (for this property).

Comment: I tried already but I need to be able to change the value from the UI. And also when I load a new "configuration file in my project", the values must be updated from the code. So OneWay/OneWayToSource/OneTime isn't what I was looking for, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**

TL;DR - `RadioButton` groups are problematic when two-way binding `IsChecked` to individual `bool` properties and the binding source changes.

The underlying problem here is that each `RadioButton`s respective `IsChecked` properties only get updated one at a time when `SelectedItem` changes. However, `RadioButton`, in grouped mode, is [programmed](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/ebe5937b557c3fa9cb29fb3a417c71652573c7e4/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/RadioButton.cs#L140) to update the other buttons in the group to false immediately when any one changes to true, which of course makes sense.

The unfortunate side effect of this is that when you change the selection there is a period when the buttons are not all pointing to the same object, yet WPF still treats the buttons as a group, so the wrong objects' `OptionX` properties are getting set to false.

Here's the step-by-step of what happens:

Initial state - buttons are unbound. Select **Foo1** in the grid.

1. `Button1.IsChecked = Foo1.Option1 (true)`. Other buttons are still unbound, no further action.
2. `Button2.IsChecked = Foo1.Option2 (false)`. No further action.
3. `Button3.IsChecked = Foo1.Option3 (false)`. No further action.

Select **Foo2** in the grid.

4. `Button1.IsChecked = Foo2.Option1 (false)`. No further action.
5. `Button2.IsChecked = Foo2.Option2 (true)`. However this also causes: `Foo2.Option1.IsChecked = Button1.IsChecked = false` and **`Foo1.Option3.IsChecked = Button3.IsChecked = false`**. The latter is not a typo; it's a mismatch, because Button3 is still bound to Foo1, though it's harmless because Foo1.Option3 was already false.
6. `Button3.IsChecked = Foo2.Option3 (false)`.

Select **Foo1** in the grid.

7. `Button1.IsChecked = Foo1.Option1 (true)`. This also causes : **`Foo2.Option2.IsChecked = Button2.IsChecked = false` and `Foo2.Option3.IsChecked = Button3.IsChecked = false`.** Another mismatch. It's harmless for Foo2.Option3 because it's false anyway, but it incorrectly forces **Foo2.Option2** to be set to false, since Button2 hasn't yet had its binding source switched back to Foo1 and thus it falses out **Foo2**.Option2 instead of Foo1.Option2.
8. `Button2.IsChecked = Foo1.Option2 (false)`.
9. `Button3.IsChecked = Foo1.Option3 (false)`.

Select **Foo2** in the grid.

10. `Button1.IsChecked = Foo2.Option1 (false)`.
11. `Button2.IsChecked = Foo2.Option2 (false)`.
12. `Button3.IsChecked = Foo2.Option3 (false)`.

So you see the problem is that the binding source changes for each `RadioButton` one at a time, rather than atomically. When any binding change results in a `RadioButton` becoming checked, the other buttons in the group are immediately affected even if their own binding sources haven't yet updated. Consequently you can't safely bind `IsChecked` with grouped `RadioButton`s to individual `bool` backing properties if the binding sources could change. Whether or not this could be called a bug in WPF is something I'll leave for others to opine on, but at least the behavior is explainable.

---

**Workaround**

If you want to stick with individual `bool` backing properties and don't want to deal with enums, one workaround would be to ungroup the `RadioButton`s and handle exclusivity on the view model side, like so:

```
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Foo(byte _id, string _name)
    {
        ID = _id;
        Name = _name;
    }
    public byte ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    bool _option1;
    public bool Option1
    {
        get => _option1;
        set
        {
            if (value == _option1)
                return;
            _option1 = value;
            if (value)
            {
                this.Option2 = false;
                this.Option3 = false;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    bool _option2;
    public bool Option2
    {
        get => _option2;
        set
        {
            if (value == _option2)
                return;
            _option2 = value;
            if (value)
            {
                this.Option1 = false;
                this.Option3 = false;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    bool _option3;
    public bool Option3 
    {
        get => _option3;
        set
        {
            if (value == _option3)
                return;
            _option3 = value;
            if (value)
            {
                this.Option1 = false;
                this.Option2 = false;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string property = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

(Don't omit the extra code for property change notification otherwise the UI won't update the other buttons when one changes).

In XAML:

```
        <StackPanel x:Name="_stack"
                    Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=DtgSource, Path=SelectedItem}">
            <RadioButton GroupName="1" 
                         IsChecked="{Binding Option1}" Content="Option 1" />
            <RadioButton GroupName="2"
                         IsChecked="{Binding Option2}" Content="Option 2" />
            <RadioButton GroupName="3"
                         IsChecked="{Binding Option3}" Content="Option 3" />
        </StackPanel>
```

Here you need to assign different group names to override the default grouping behavior.

**Other Workarounds**

One drawback of the enum-less workaround is that it doesn't scale well and can lead to subtle errors if you don't false-out the right properties each time.

If you're willing to use enums instead, Sir Rufo's example in the comment below is great and deserves to be its own answer. Another good alternative (my preferred actually) is the accepted answer to this question:

[How do you work around the binding problems with radio button groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61890512/how-do-you-work-around-the-binding-problems-with-radio-button-groups)

The reason these work whereas the individual `bool` property bindings don't is a bit subtle, but ultimately they both prevent the backing property from being altered when a `RadioButton` gets unchecked by the UI due to being in a mutually exclusive group.

Comment: The data structure and the visualization does not match. The OP should change Foo to use an enum for Options or use CheckBoxes for Option 1 to 3. Anyway, this is the correct answer to the question :o)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answers. This is the workaround I ended up using with the original project checkboxes. So yes, the answer is correct and it works. However I'm curious and would like to understand what exactly is going on in the original implementation if it's a bug or normal behavior whose reason is a bit unclear to me. :)

Comment: @tstx If there is only Option you can choose (RadioButtons make only sense in that case) then your data is wrong. It all should look like [this](https://gist.github.com/SirRufo/33a647718704d5f57cb88f40d9f8a02d)

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. When you say "your data is wrong", what do you mean exactly? That binding 3 boolean to 3 radiobuttons from the same group shouldn't be linked this way but trough an enumerate instead?

Comment: @tstx I dug in deeper (including into the WPF source code) and identified the underlying cause of what was happening. Hope it makes sense. About the data model and using enums instead, I also personally prefer to use RadioButton's with a single backing enum, but that wouldn't necessarily solve this issue. Any time a `RadioButton`'s `IsChecked` two-way binding source changes, and it's part of a group, you are going to have this problem. Many years ago I gave up on using `RadioButton` groups entirely because of this kind of behavior and always implement exclusivity viewmodel side.

Comment: By the way, out of curiosity, where did you look for the source code of the RadioButton? maybe next time I'll try to take a look before asking here

Comment: @tstx oh sure see the link in my updated answer. But don't fret, it's still not obvious what's going on unless you break inside the view model setters and inspect each RadioButton's binding source at the time they're updated. Then you'll see that immediately following the grid selection the RBs aren't all bound to the same source view model.

Comment: Also check out the accepted answer here for another alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61890512/how-do-you-work-around-the-binding-problems-with-radio-button-groups